# predefine date to display on datepicker in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, datepicker, android-datepicker

Im trying to have my datepicker display the predefined date that I have set when I click on it.
I have tried using a delimiter to separate the date and setting them based on the year, month and day but it still does not work. it keeps on displaying the current date instead of the date i set

```
val date = '03-22-2022'
 val startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        val startPicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year)
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month)
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth)
            
        }

        editstartdatepicker.setOnClickListener{
            val dialog = DatePickerDialog(this,
                startPicker,
                startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            dialog.show()

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize startCalender as it's pointing to current date
use this

```
    val date = "03-22-2022"
    val startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    startCalendar.time = sdf.parse(date)
```

Comment: do i have to remove any lines? Im still getting the current day.  as my date is from a textview i used startCalendar.time = sdf.parse(textview.text.toString()). I currently have this line at setonclicklistener

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove any lines just add this before creating the picker dialog
like first thing inside your onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

may it helps

```
  DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
datePicker.updateDate(2016, 5, 22);
```

Comment: is there a way to update this if my date is a string and in mm-dd-yyyy format ? like '03-22-2022'

Comment: Yes , you can use the simple date format  as shown below.        ->   val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM")          ->  val date = Date()
Set whatever date you want to in your date picker and set the date into dialog picker by using this line..  ->datePciker.updateDate(dateFormat.format(date))